# Derivative limit is uniformly convergent

Tags: analysis, derivatives, convergence-divergence

If we consider the sequence of functions: $g_{n}(x)=\frac{f(x+h_{n})-f(x)}{h_{n}}$ where $h_{n}>0$ is a sequence of real numbers converging to $0$, and $f$ is a $C^{1}$ function. How can you show that the sequence {$g_{n}$} is uniformly convergent?

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is incorrect. For a counterexample, consider $f(x)=\ln(x)\in C^1(0,1)$.

**Proof** Consider $h_n=\frac1n$. Let $\epsilon = \ln(2)-1$ and consider any $N\in \Bbb{N}$. Consider $x= \frac1N$.  Then $|g_N(x)-g(x)|=\left|\frac{\ln((x+\frac1N)/x)}{\frac1N}-\frac1x\right|=\left| N\ln\left( 1+\frac{1}{Nx}\right)-\frac1x\right|=N(\ln(2)-1)\geq\epsilon$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Use the Mean-Value Theorem to show that

$$|g_n(x)-f'(x)|=|f'(x+\theta_n (x)h_n)-f'(x)|$$

for some $0<\theta_n (x)<1$.

Then, use the continuity of $f'$ to show that for any $\epsilon$ there exists a number $N$, such that $n>N$ implies that

$$|g_n(x)-f'(x)|=|f'(x+\theta_n (x)h_n)-f'(x)|<\epsilon$$

Remember that $0<\theta_n(x)<1$, so that $|\theta_n(x) h_n|<1$.

Comment: Note that the value of $N$ in your argument depends on $\epsilon$ as well as $x$. For uniform convergence it is necessary to show that $N$ depends on $\epsilon$ only and is independent of $x$. To ensure this we need to have not just continuity but uniform continuity of $f'(x)$. This would be the case if we are dealing with the function $f'(x)$ on a closed interval. But this is not given in question.